# array_unshift on multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this result from `var_dump` for a multidimensional array:

```
array (size=6)
  'sambalpur.in.net' => 
    array (size=2)
      'classkey' => string 'indotnet' (length=8)
      'status' => string 'available' (length=9)
  'sambalpur.com' => 
    array (size=2)
      'classkey' => string 'domcno' (length=6)
      'status' => string 'regthroughothers' (length=16)
  'sambalpur.info' => 
    array (size=2)
      'classkey' => string 'dominfo' (length=7)
      'status' => string 'regthroughothers' (length=16)
  'sambalpur.net' => 
    array (size=2)
      'classkey' => string 'dotnet' (length=6)
      'status' => string 'regthroughothers' (length=16)
  'sambalpur.biz' => 
    array (size=2)
      'classkey' => string 'dombiz' (length=6)
      'status' => string 'available' (length=9)
  'sambalpur.in' => 
    array (size=2)
      'classkey' => string 'dotin' (length=5)
      'status' => string 'regthroughothers' (length=16)
```

Now say I want to shift this specific array to the beginning of array:

```
'sambalpur.biz' => 
        array (size=2)
          'classkey' => string 'dombiz' (length=6)
          'status' => string 'available' (length=9)
```

I have tried:

```
array_unshift($array,array('sambalpur.biz'));
```

But what I am getting is like this:

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'sambalpur.biz' (length=13)
  'sambalpur.in.net' => 
    array (size=2)
      'classkey' => string 'indotnet' (length=8)
      'status' => string 'available' (length=9)
  'sambalpur.com' => 
    array (size=2)
      'classkey' => string 'domcno' (length=6)
      'status' => string 'regthroughothers' (length=16)
  'sambalpur.info' => 
    array (size=2)
      'classkey' => string 'dominfo' (length=7)
      'status' => string 'regthroughothers' (length=16)
  'sambalpur.net' => 
    array (size=2)
      'classkey' => string 'dotnet' (length=6)
      'status' => string 'regthroughothers' (length=16)
  'sambalpur.biz' => 
    array (size=2)
      'classkey' => string 'dombiz' (length=6)
      'status' => string 'available' (length=9)
  'sambalpur.in' => 
    array (size=2)
      'classkey' => string 'dotin' (length=5)
      'status' => string 'regthroughothers' (length=16)
```

What is the correct way to shift the array?

Comment: `array_unshift` is for adding additional elements to an array, not rearranging it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought I had done this before but couldn't find a duplicate:

```
$array = array_splice($array,
                      array_search('sambalpur.biz', array_keys($array)), 1) + $array;
```

- Get a numerically indexed array of the keys with `array_keys()`
- Search the returned array for `sambalpur.biz` with `array_search()`
- Use the returned index to cut out that element with `array_splice()`
- Add that to the existing array

Along the same line as *Don't Panic*:

```
$array = array_merge(array('sambalpur.biz' => $array['sambalpur.biz']), $array);
```

No need to unset as the order of insertion dictates which key overwrites the other so this one overwrites the previous one.

Comment: Your last suggestion is much much better.

Comment: Ah, good catch. I did feel like I was missing something with the `array_merge` suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You can `uksort` the array, using the specific key you want to move to the beginning in the comparison function.

```
$key = 'sambalpur.biz';
uksort($array, function($a, $b) use ($key) {
    if ($a == $key) return -1;
    if ($b == $key) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

This should move that item to the beginning without changing the order of the other items.

---

Another possibility is to remove the child array, and then merge the main array back onto it.

```
$key = 'sambalpur.biz';
$x = $array[$key];
unset($array[$key]);
$array = array_merge([$key => $x], $array);
```

Comment: I have already tested your first suggestion, it is working fine. Let me check the second one.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to stem from array_unshift() reindexing elements you are passing. If you wanted to prepend your second array to your first array though and preserve indexes, you can use the + operator (`$firstArray = $secondArray + $firstArray`);

Comment: But first you need to get `$secondArray` out of `$firstArray`.

Comment: Huh, just realized that the OP wanted to rearrange his array and not prepend new elements. Got confused since he was using array_unshift(). In that case, one liner by @AbraCadaver should do the trick.